# Help with PHP Cookies and some basic authentication

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to use some really basic authentication... basically, I want to put my site live but have one password that I can send out to a few people so they can access it and not anybody else.

I've been trying to use cookies, but I'm relatively inexperienced with them. The code that follows is what I have so far.

**At the top of my header.** This for some reason doesn't redirect to authenticate.php

```
<?php if(!isset($_COOKIE["user"])) header("Location: authenticate.php?invalid=0"); ?>
```

**authenticate.php**

```
<?php
    if($_GET["invalid"] == 1)   {
        echo '<p> Invalid password. </p>';
    }
        echo '<form action="enter.php" method="post">

                <span>Enter the password</span><br />
                <textarea name="mainPass"></textarea>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit!" />
            </form>';

?>
```

**enter.php**

```
<?php
    $pass = $_POST['mainPass'];
    if(strstr($pass, "<password removed>")) {
        setcookie("user", time()+3600);
        header("Location: index.php");
    } else {
        header("Location: authenticate.php?invalid=1    ");
    }
?>
```

Comment: put exit() after your headers. Then it should redirect correctly.

Comment: also its better to avoid ending php tag ?> if it placed at the end of the page.

Comment: @Bob That causes nothing to happen instead, doesn't redirect at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

quick and dirty. don't use this for long. does not require any forms. set the username and password hardcoded into the function code itself. you must run the function at the top of every page for this to work.

```
    // quick and dirty http authentication
    function authenticateHttp() {
        @session_start();
        // credential check
        if (!isset($_SESSION['auth_realm']) || !isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
            // credentials not supplied yet
            // send http credential request
            $_SESSION['auth_realm'] = uniqid('', true);
            header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="' . $_SESSION['auth_realm'] . '"');
            header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
            // if cancel button clicked, show this
            exit('You must authenticate before accessing this area.');
        } else {
            // credentials supplied
            if ($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] !== '{your chosen username}' || $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] !== '{your chosen password}') {
                unset($_SESSION['auth_realm']);
                exit('You have entered an invalid login.');
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: EDIT: added the @session_start() at the beginning of the function. almost forgot.

Comment: @dqhendricks Your function causes an error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF` at the first if statement

Comment: @dqhendricks at the first if statement in the function

Comment: @Tory Waterman do you have a semi-colon after @session_start();

Comment: @dqhendricks Ok that works now, but if they give a wrong login once it doesn't display the login ever again... Where can I place a session_destroy that will fix this?

Comment: Ah, perhaps move unset($_SESSION['auth_realm']); above that if statement instead. I'll edit the original post to show you.

Comment: @dqhendricks That causes the login window to pop up every time regardless of a correct username/password

Comment: @dqhendricks We're close. login window still pops up every time... entering correct credentials results in `You have entered an invalid login.`

Comment: @Tory Waterman oops got it. Now see above code. Only unsets realm if wrong login used... wasn't thinking clearly. goes to show, always test your code!@

Comment: @Tory Waterman also, note that you may unset realm to "log out".

Comment: @dqhendricks that code still causes the same problem. are you sure you edited the above code? the edit time is before your last comment

Comment: @Tory Waterman I just copied and pasted from the above and tested it. it works. once logged in your are logged in for good. if you get a wrong password, you can refresh to try again. works good all around. maybe you copied an older version?

Comment: @dqhendricks A couple possibilities... the only things I need to change are `your chosen username` and `your chosen password` right? [Here's the code I'm using](http://dpaste.com/558496/plain/). I'm fairly sure we're using the same version...

Comment: @dqhendricks Is it possible this is causing problems because I am on localhost?

Comment: @Tory Waterman Yes that should be the only thing you change. The only thing I can think is happening, is that the session data is not saving somehow? What exactly is happening? It asks for username each time? Check the session variable for auth_realm, and make sure that it is saving after a correct login.

Comment: @dqhendricks Yes, every time I go it asks for a username/pass. When I enter the correct stuff, it tells me invalid... refreshing causes the login to pop up again. The auth_realm seems to be a variation of `4e04e89bb9c6d0.85123883` every time.

Comment: @Tory Waterman it sounds like the username and password simply aren't matching, you removed the brackets right? '{your chosen username}' should equal your username, so you would change it to something like 'genericusername', and likewise with the password.